# .htaccess rewrite rule for self made MVC application

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes, url-routing

I have created a small web application in PHP and I am struggling with the .htaccess file

I have this file structure:

**/Main Project**

**//App**
// controllers, models, core, views

**//Public**
// css

What i did till now is to redirect from localhost directly to the /public folder like this:

   `RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^$ /public/ [L]`

How I can do it to work the same as localhost/public/controller/action/params but just localhost/controller/action/param1/param2 ?

Thank you in advance for trying to help me!

Comment: Is this your own framework? Almost all frameworks (like laravel) has routes.

Comment: Yes its mine, i was building it to have a better understanding of mvc

Comment: Learn Laravel, it's a respite!

Comment: I know Laravel :) It was just a why not project :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying it this days i found a solution for me and i can redirect to the public folder and also pass the controllers, methods and parameters. If somebody will have the same example, here is what works for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is basically the Laravel example :)